# .this reference error in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, this, jsx, babeljs

In my react application i have code like below.the error occurring is **undefined removeOperation**.when i checked online the error is because of the **this.** function reference and the solution to that is using **.bind(this)**.Plz somebody help me where i can use this bind ,i have tried in many ways everthing leads to error

```
   fields = this.state.operations.map(function(operation,index){
          if(operation == "adjust-price-multiply"){
                return (<PriceMultiply key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
          }else if(operation == "adjust-price-add"){
                 return (<PriceAdd key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
          }else if(operation == "filter-products-includes"){
                  return (<IncludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
          }else if(operation == "filter-products-excludes"){
                  return (<ExcludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do this:

```
fields = this.state.operations.map(function(operation,index){
      if(operation == "adjust-price-multiply"){
            return (<PriceMultiply key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "adjust-price-add"){
             return (<PriceAdd key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "filter-products-includes"){
              return (<IncludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "filter-products-excludes"){
              return (<ExcludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }
}.bind(this));
```

Or if you are useing some sort of ES6 transpiling (babel) `this` is automatically bound when using the ES6 arrow function syntax (`()=>{}`instead of `function() {}`):

```
fields = this.state.operations.map((operation,index) => {
      if(operation == "adjust-price-multiply"){
            return (<PriceMultiply key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "adjust-price-add"){
             return (<PriceAdd key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "filter-products-includes"){
              return (<IncludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }else if(operation == "filter-products-excludes"){
              return (<ExcludeProducts key={index} removeOperation={this.removeOperation} />);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Marius the first method didn't work ,the second way works perfectly